# How to check a string contains only int in JAVA?

Tags: java

I hope to write a small method to do the following things:
For example, the string a = "a123", then the method should return fulse;
the string b = "111", it should return true.
It means only the string is an int, it should return true, all the other cases should return false.
Does anyone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: negative case? "-1345" ?

Comment: Seems like a homework question to me... add a homework tag if so

Comment: @awashburn Homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: @A.R.S. I did not know that the homework tag was depreciated ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Integer.parseInt(integerString);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public boolean isInteger(String integerString){

   try{
      Integer.parseInt(integerString);
      return true;
   } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      return false;
   }
}
```

a NumberFormatException means parsing will not be successful hence the String is not an integer.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant you wanted a string that's composed *only* of the digits 0-9 (and with arbitrary length) you can just use the regular expression `"\\d+"`, i.e. `str.matches("\\d+")`.

If you want to take into account positive and negative signs you could use `"[+-]?\\d+"`.

If you're considered with length (the primitive `int` typo can't have more than 10 digits) you could use `"[+-]?\\d{1,10}+"`.

Comment: That good for number validation, but integer has also some length.

Comment: No. What I meant is integer is shorten than long. `+` is only responsible for that empty string is not treated as valid.